# Why if I am using Podman Desktop, and a kind cluster, images are not seen by the cluster when run kubectl apply pod creation fails, ImagePullBackOff

Tags: containers, command-line-interface, kubectl, podman, kind

podman version 4.6.2,
Windows machine

when I create an image with the cli is not seen by kind instead images created via UI are?
Pods creation fails with ErrImagePool, ImagePullBackOff.

Try to follow this https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/kubernetes-kind-load-docker-image/ , but it doesnt work, do I need to manually load the images via podman cli command or some "linking"?

https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/kubernetes-kind-load-docker-image/ not work
and from UI (Podman Desktop) it works

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with kind. Podman and Docker (used by kind!?) maintain state (images, containers etc.) in distinct folders. Other Kubernetes distros no longer use Docker but a lower-level runtime called containerd. Suffice to say, it's expected that you won't see transparency between Podman and Kubernetes **but** you can usually use a container registry to transfer images between the two. It appears that kind has a local registry (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/#using-the-registry). You can tag/push Podman images to this registry and then use them with kind.